# assigning the valueas from the list python

Tags: python, list, function

How to assign the value from b list? I need to return the value for 3 a[2]

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
b=[6,7,9,9,10]
x=a[2] #for example for 3
```

Result:
9

Comment: Are you asking how to use an `int` from the `list` `a` to fetch that `index` of the list `b`?

Comment: You haven't shown us how you want `b` used.

Comment: @HampusLarsson yes

Comment: Okay, so. When `2` was the index you wanted to use to index into `a`, you wrote `a[2]`. So, when `x` is the index you want to use to index into `b`.... see a pattern?

Comment: To build on the code you've written already; When you assign `x` using `x=a[2]`, you're fetching the value inside of `a` that has the index of `2` and assigning it to the variable `x`. In this case, that is the integer `3`. Now that you have that variable, you can use `x` to recall `3` later in the code. Now, what would be the next step to use `x` to index `b`?